# Mongoose: Search for any user's Posts and Display them

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am attempting to allow a user to type in any username and find all associated "posts" from that username. I have a model set up below which allows user's to post information/comments.

How would a user be able to type in a username in an input field and generate all associated data/comments for that username? Possible?

Here is my mongoose model:

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String

    }
})
```